# Get children's children count in Umbraco

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

How can I count the children's children nodes? I have this code so far:

```
@foreach (var newsYear in CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible"))
{
    @newsYear.Name (@newsYear.Children.Count()) @*Number of children's children*@
    @foreach (var newsMonth in newsYear.Children.Where("Visible"))
    {
        @newsMonth.Name (@newsMonth.Children.Count())
    }
}
```

Comment: So what does not work? Have you tried `newsYear.ChildrenAsList.Count()` ?

Comment: No, this code is working in this way, but I need to now to number of the children's children after the first foreach. So something like that `@newsYear.Children.Children.Count()`, but this isn't working.

Comment: are you trying to show HTML in your second line? your code is correct, you have to wrap it in some html tag or use `@Html.Raw()` to show it on screen.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code, it looks like you are trying to display the total number of all news articles for the current year?

```
 @newsYear.Name (@newsYear.Children.Count())
```

However, this would return the count for all the 'month' nodes, assuming you are following the following structure:

Year > Month OR Year > Month > Day

If you want the Total number of articles for the current month (in loop), then try the following:

```
@newsYear.Children.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("YourNewsDocTypeAliasHere")).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SelectMany()` to do this.

```
var allItems = CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible").ToList();
foreach (var newsYear in allItems)
{
    var yearTotal = allItems.SelectMany(c => c.Children).Count();
    foreach (var newsMonth in newsYear.Children)
    {
        var monthTotal = newsMonth.Children.Count();
    }
}
```